# TypeScript Call Signature Example

Tags: typescript

So I'm reading [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures) documentation and am really confused how this is even possible in JavaScript.

```
type DescribableFunction = {
   description: string;
   (a: any): boolean;
};
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
   console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
};

doSomething((()=>false)); // Argument of type '() => false' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DescribableFunction'. Property 'description' is missing in type '() => false' but required in type 'DescribableFunction'.

doSomething({description: 'test'}); // fn is not a function.
```

As you can see above, how can the param `fn` be both object and function at the same time..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are a special type of object - they're essentially *callable objects*.

```js
const fn = () => {};
console.log(fn instanceof Object);
```

The prototype chain for a function is:

```
fn <- Function.prototype <- Object.prototype
```

And objects can have arbitrary key-value pairs put on them.

```js
'use strict';
const fn = () => {};
fn.prop = 'val';
console.log('prop is:', fn.prop);
```

So, for an example of how the function in your question could work, you could do:

```
const fn = Object.assign(
  () => false,
  { description: 'test' }
);

doSomething(fn);
```

Now `fn` is both callable and has a `description` property which is a string.